# Multiple (identical) EventListeners on the same Element, why?

Tags: javascript

I tried to find an explanation but running out of things I can search for. I know this seems like a stupid question, but I am losing hope.

When I do the following, I get the behavior I would expect. I click button_2 and an eventListener is added to button_1.

```js
const button_1 = document.getElementById("btn-1");
const button_2 = document.getElementById("btn-2");

const someFunction = () => {
    console.log("foo");
};

const addEvent = () => {
    button_1.addEventListener("click", someFunction);
};

button_2.addEventListener("click", addEvent);
```

However, when I try this and I click button_2 repeatedly, I end up with multiple eventListeners, all attached to button_1 which fire all at once when I click it. Why?

```js
const button_1 = document.getElementById("btn-1");
const button_2 = document.getElementById("btn-2");

const addEvent = () => {
    const someFunction = () => {
        console.log("foo");
    };
    button_1.addEventListener("click", someFunction);
};

button_2.addEventListener("click", addEvent);
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first code example, `someFunction` is declared **once** and then applied as an event listener multiple times. Since each time it is applied it is the **same function**, it doesn't get added again.

In the second example, `someFunction` is declared *inside* the `addEvent` function; each time `addEvent` is called a **new** function is created and assigned to `someFunction` and then added as an event listener.

Since the functions are different (albeit *identical*), they are treated as separate functions and all added.

Comment: Thank you very much! That makes total sense.
But this also means that doing it this way is, in general, a bad approach, cause this problem will (or rather would) appear all the time?

Comment: @SMEETT It's the same issue if you try to use `removeEventListener`. It won't work with multiple instances of the same named function either, only if you try to remove the same instance. Once you understand this you will know in future and code accordingly

Comment: @charlietfl I tried to use removeEventListener (and monitored the button with 'getEventListeners' in Chrome), and it behaves like you say. removeEventListener does nothing. I wasn't aware that a new instance of the function is created each time, since the name is identical (and that still seems odd to me.) Thanks for your reply!